# Dando permissão a outra aplicação para acessar meu pacote

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma aplicação que tem um determinado arquivo de áudio, que fica em `/data/data/meu_pacote/audio_anexo/audio.mp3`, até ai tudo bem, o problema é que a classe MediaPlayer do Android não consegue executar o arquivo, **e quando eu coloco o mesmo arquivo no cartão de memória, ele executa sem problemas**.

Acredito eu que como a pasta `/data/data/meu_pacote` pertence somente a minha aplicação, o MediaPlayer não consegue acessar o conteúdo que fica dentro dela.

Qual a solução?

Obs: Já procurei pelo `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE`.

Segue abaixo o código para criação do arquivo de áudio, que estou usando. Há algum parâmetro que eu precise passar?

```
File diraudio = new File("/data/data/br.meupacote.meuapp/audio_anexo/");
//Verifica se o diretorio nao existe e cria ele;
if(!diraudio.exists())
{
    Log.i("XDEBUG","Pasta para áudio foi criada!");
    diraudio.mkdir();
}

String caminho = dir + audiofile.getName();

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(audiofile);
byte[] b = IOUtils.toBytes(in);

File file = new File(caminho);  

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(b);
```

Comment: De uma olhada em ContentProviders, talvez de para compartilhar os arquivos usando essa funcionalidade: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o maior problema que esteja a impossibilitar a leitura do ficheiro e a sua localização.
A solução que encontrei quando precisei ler um ficheiro guardado com o meu projecto foi colocar o ficheiro na pasta: MeuProjecto->assets.

Para poder ler o ficheiro abrir o ficheiro "mp3" usando o MediaPlayer segue-se o exemplo de um metodo que criei:

```
 public void tocaMusica(String nomeFicheiro) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException 
 {
     AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = null;
     try 
     {
        descriptor = getActivity().getAssets().openFd(nomeFicheiro);
     } 
     catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     player = new MediaPlayer();

     //Definimos duas variaveis com o inicio e o fim da reproducao do ficheiro que obetmos dos metodos getStartOffset e getLength
     long start = descriptor.getStartOffset();
     long end = descriptor.getLength();

     //Definimos o DataSource do player com o ficheiro que pegamos usando o AssetFileDescriptor e o inicio e o fim do ficheiro.
     player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
     player.prepare();

     player.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
     player.start();

    }
```

Para tocar a musica basta invocar o metodo tocaMusica com o nome do ficheiro dentro da pasta assets da seguinte maneira:

```
tocaMusica("teste.mp3");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, optei em colocar o arquivo no cartão de memória mesmo, pois tinha que entregar o projeto. Assim que possível irei testar o seu método. Obrigado mais uma vez!